# Conditional validation for a field on submit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

To add a required validation conditionally to "imageString" field on Submit. But its not set the required validation as expected.

Initializing the form.

```
constructor(){
 this.poeForm = this.fb.group({
      imageString: [""],
      imageFileName: [""],
    }
 }
}
```

Invoked save, set validation for imageString field.

```
   saveForm() {
       this.profileImgValidator();
       this.getFormValidationErrors();
       if (this.poeForm.invalid) {
          Swal.fire("Please fill in all the required fields");
          return;
        }
      }
```

actual logic for setting value.

```
 profileImgValidator(){
    let errors = null;
    this.mandatoryFields = //server call it will return value or null
    if(this.mandatoryFields){     
        this.poeForm.get('imageString').setValidators(Validators.required);
      }else{
        this.poeForm.get('imageString').clearValidators();
      }    
    return errors;
  }
```

Checked by iterating through form controls.

```
 getFormValidationErrors() {
    Object.keys(this.poeForm.controls).forEach(key => {
    const controlErrors: ValidationErrors = this.poeForm.get(key).errors;
    if (controlErrors != null) {
          Object.keys(controlErrors).forEach(keyError => {
            console.log('Key control: ' + key + ', keyError: ' + keyError + ', err value: ', controlErrors[keyError]);
          });
        }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular Reactive Form has a [custom validators](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators), and  here it makes perfect sense to use that.

```
this.poeForm = this.fb.group({
  imageString: [""],
  imageFileName: [""],
 }, { validators: profileImgValidator } // use custom validator
}

export const profileImgValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
 const imageString = control.get('imageString').value;

 if (this.mandatoryFields) {
   return imageString ? null : { required: true }
 }

 return null;
};
```

Comment: +1 This is absolutely the correct approach but his validator is or was going to be asynchronous so it's worth mentioning that it's also supported `asyncValidator`

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

```
profileImgValidator() {
  let errors = null;
  this.mandatoryFields = //server call it will return value or null
  
  const item = this.poeForm.get('imageString');
  if (this.mandatoryFields) {
    item.clearValidators();
    item.setValidators(Validators.required);
  } else {
    item.clearValidators();
  }

  item.updateValueAndValidity();
  this.poeForm.updateValueAndValidity();

  return errors;
}
```